# How to highlight clicked menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using following code to show vertical navigation. It can collapse and open, i like to change this when user click sub menu, parent menu keep opened and sub menu highlighted.So user know that which page he displaying. I am using Meteor JS and bootstrap 3, I googled it and i think i have to write some javaScript.But i have very little experience in javascript.

```
<template name="sideMenu">
<div class="content">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                        Home
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Articles
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    News
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Report
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                        About us
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/mission"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Articles
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    News
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Report
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        Company
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/mission"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Articles
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    News
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>
                                    Report
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zevsuld/ygNQj/)

Comment: could you provide a fiddle for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zevsuld/ygNQj/ this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('.panel-body .table td').on('click', function() {
    $('.panel-body .table td').css('background', 'none');
    $(this).css('background', 'black');
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygNQj/1/)

Comment: Sreekesh Okky thanks! it seems the perfect solution. It is not working on my project though( I think there is some other problem),but I think I will figure it out.Thanks again

Comment: @zevsuld which jQuery version do you use?

Comment: jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.0